# Hibernate Envers - Audit tables are not inserted in Spring-Hibernate-envers application

Tags: hibernate, spring

I am using Hibernate v3.6.0 Fianl with Spring v3.0.5. I configured Post-insert audit listener of Envers and it is being called after inserting data into the primary table, but it is not inserting into audit table. It is printing insert query for primary table into console, but not for audit table. 
I see RelationDescription relDesc = entCfg.getRelationDescription(propertyName); code in EntitiesConfigurations class and relDesc is null for all my properties of entity class.

I am using JPA annotations on my entity class, but using Hibernate ORM. I have @audited annotation on my class.

Post insert event get called after inserting into main table, but no data in audit table. I debugged the Envers code, it was not failing anywhere.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Envers heavily relies on properly configured transaction management, if you use some kind of auto commit Envers wouldn't work. Make sure transaction management is properly configured in your case, see [10. Transaction Management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) and [13.3 Hibernate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Here is my transaction configuration from xml:  <tx:jta-transaction-manager/> <tx:annotation-driven/>. I am using @Transactional annotation on my service. I am running application in websphere v6.1. Please let me know.\

Comment: Your answer about Transaction directed me to right direction. I am using websphere and had to add the following hibernate properties to make Envers to work: These are addition to <tx:jta-transaction-manager/> .      hibernate.transaction.factory_class=org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory
    hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class=org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup
Thanks for your help.